# Distribution of synaptic connections

Tags: neuroscience, brain, synapses

What is the roughly the distribution of the various synaptic connections in the brain.

Consider the following types:

- **axoaxonic synapse** between the axon of one neuron and the axon of another neuron.
- **axodendritic synapse** between the axon of one neuron and the dendrites of another.
- **axodendrosomatic synapse** between a neuron's axon and the dendrites and body of another.
- **axosomatic synapse** between the axon of one neuron and the body of another.
- **dendrodendritic synapse** from a dendrite of one cell to a dendrite of another.

I know that the **axodendritic synapse** is the most prevalent, but what is order of the others? Are there any sources for this (couldn't find this *anywhere*). Specifically, rough percentages of the distribution (amount) of these synaptic connections in the nervous system would be very helpful.

Comment: The adult human brain contains ~86 billion neurons with trillions of synapses [estimated at 0.15 quadrillion](http://www.dana.org/News/Details.aspx?id=43512). I am unsure if this question can be answered.

Comment: @AliceD I understand that there are many synapses, but don't we know anything about which synaptic connections are more common than others?

Comment: I expect there may be studies that have addressed *some* of the various connections in particular brain structures, but to find data that provide an order of appearance of *all* of your mentioned connections in the *whole brain*, I am doubtful of. It's an intriguing question, though. It's quite of a textbook question and I doubt a literature search will be helpful.

Comment: @AliceD I understand, but I couldn't find the answer in three different textbooks. That's why I'm asking the question here. Maybe somebody knows a study about this?

Comment: It would be good to mention those textbooks - it may save people work. If I would give this question a try I would start looking in Kandel's Principles of Neural Science - did you check that? if not, I'm happy to look once I'm back in the lab. Might take me a few days.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but here is a study on the hippocampal CA1 pyramidal neuron that makes an exhaustive catalog of all synapse types and locations: Megías, M., Z. Emri, T. F. Freund, and A. I. Gulyás. “Total Number and Distribution of Inhibitory and Excitatory Synapses on Hippocampal CA1 Pyramidal Cells.” Neuroscience 102, no. 3 (2001): 527–40.  I know such papers exist for a few other cell types. This paper might provide a lead for finding those too.

Comment: @yamad Perfect! I'll take a look at that one and see if I can find others.

Comment: Are you still interested in this kind of questions? Have a look at mine: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53587/the-human-brain-in-numbers-i-neurons, https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/63950/the-human-brain-in-numbers-ii-synaptic-connections