# The human brain in numbers I: neurons

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience, brain, neuroanatomy

Even though knowing the number of neurons in a functional unit or with the same function is not of main importance, it may be interesting to know their orders of magnitude, especially in the human brain. For example:

```
|------------------|------------------|
| cerebellum       | 100,000,000,000  |    
| cortex           |  20,000,000,000  |    
| telencephalon    |  10,000,000,000  |    
| brainstem        |   1,000,000,000  |    
| sensory neurons  |                  |     
|          haptic  |     500,000,000  |     
|          visual  |     100,000,000  |
|        auditory  |           2,000  |
| limbic system    |                  |    
|         amygdala |      10,000,000  |   
|------------------|------------------|
```

Surely, for many parts of brain you will find a reference where the number of its neurons is estimated (e.g. for the [amygdala](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/26/29/7674.long)) - when you search hard enough. I also found [The Human Brain in Numbers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2776484/) where *some* numbers are given. But I am looking for a reference where *many* of these numbers are given in a systematic way, ideally in a table like the one above. Is there any?

Comment: For which parts do you want such numbers? The more detail you go into, the more likely you are to get nothing. It would be, say, easier to get info on the 4 lobes than on hundreds of areas. So, do you want info on simply the 4 lobes?

Comment: As many as possible;-) My interest is not specific but general. And please do not ask, why I want these numbers: I just want to know which ones exist or are known (approximately).

Comment: A related question - yielding a [partial answer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2672563/) - can be found here: [What are the estimates in total neurons and average connections per neuron for each of the processing areas of the visual cortex?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/12945/what-are-the-estimates-in-total-neurons-and-average-connections-per-neuron-for-e?rq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, let me clear out that these numbers are calculated, not observed (obviously, nobody has counted the number of neurons in any part of brain). So, take these with a grain of salt.

I was unable to find any report that collects and displays all numbers together (Bio Numbers too didn't yield significant information). So I will compile here all the numbers I have found so far (and keep adding as I find more):

```
|----------------------|------------------|------------------------|
|PART OF BRAIN         |NUMBER OF NEURONS |               REFERENCE|
|----------------------|------------------|------------------------|
|The human brain       | over 120 billion |  Herculano-Houzel, 2009| 
|Telencephalon         |  12-15 billion   |           Shariff, 1953|
|Cerebellum            |   101 billion    |    Anderson et al, 1992|
|Cerebral cortex       |  21-26 billion   |      Pelvig et al, 2008|
|Amygdaloid complex    |    12 million    |    Schumann et al, 2005|
|Hippocampus (CA1)     |  11-24 million   |        West et al, 1990|
|Brainstem             |   < 1 billion    |  Herculano-Houzel, 2009|
|Visual cortex         |   140 million    |       Leuba et al, 1994|
|Auditory cortex       |    1 billion     |University of Washington|
|Corpus callosum       |   200 million    |          Healthline.com|
|Spinal cord           |    1 billion     |University of Washington|
|Cortical minicolumn   |      80-120      |               Wikipedia|
|Cortical hypercolumn  |   5,000-10,000   |               Wikipedia|
|----------------------|------------------|------------------------|
```

I will continue adding more numbers as I find them. Again, nobody will claim these numbers to be exact, these are just estimates from calculations. Even different sources show different numbers. For example, the Washington University page puts the number of neurons in visual cortex to 528 million. Thus, don't expect these numbers to be anywhere near exact.

[image: human brain]

**References:**

- [Herculano-Houzel, 2009](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2776484/?report=classic)
- [Shariff, 1953](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/13069628)
- [Anderson *et al*, 1992](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1484123)
- [Pelvig *et al*, 2008](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17544173)
- [Schumann *et al*, 2005](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2572713/)
- [West *et al*, 1990](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2358525)
- [Leuba *et al* 1994](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00187293)
- [University of Washington](https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/facts.html)
- [Healthline.com](http://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps/corpus-callosum)
- Wikipedia [Cortical minicolumn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_minicolumn#Number_of_neurons_in_a_minicolumn)
- Wikipedia [Cortical hypercolumn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_column)

Comment: Just great! More than I did expect.

Comment: It would be great if the table was hierarchically organised (where possible): top level: the human brain. Way down: the amygdala,...

Comment: @hansstricker again, I don't get you. How are you categorizing them to get a hierarchy? From front to back? Number of neurons?

Comment: I mean hierarchized by being-part-of. Doesn't this make sense, at least sometimes? I mean, some parts of the brain are immediate parts of the brain (cerebrum, brainstem, cerebellum), others are parts of parts, and so on.

Comment: May I add the numbers for cortical minicolumns (ca. 100) and cortical hypercolumns (ca. 100 x 100) in your table?

Comment: @hansstricker with proper citations, why not? Every answer, including mine, on Biology.SE is open for improvement! Right now I am quite busy, so will not be able to help anyone out much :)

Comment: @HomoSapien: This is a hierarchy which I have in mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_in_the_human_brain . It would be great to have this with the acoording number of neurons.

Comment: 120 billion? I always thought it was closer to 90 billion.

Comment: @forest however surprising it is, its just a scientific claim. You never know until you count them all :P