# Any volumetric data for areas of the brain?

Tags: brain, neuroanatomy, synapses

I was trying to write an overview of AI and wanted to quantify some numerical data about the brain.  It is easy to find many sources quoting 100 billion neurons.  However, I would like to get the number of neurons (obviously approximate) in each area.  Also, while I can find the average number of synapses to neuron, it would be nice to know if there are higher numbers is certain areas of the brain.

This is not my field, it would simply be instructive to generate a table of data.
Is there any source, even approximate volume for different areas of the brain?

Comment: Not volume, but number of neurons in distinct coarse areas: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2776484/#B46

Comment: For the number of neurons, assuming you are referring to the human brain: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53587