# The human brain in numbers II: synaptic connections

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

The overall number of synapses in the human brain is roughly 1,000 trillion, i.e. 10,000 synapses per neuron.

My question here is three-fold:

1. I assume that each [structural type of neuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron#Classification) (basket, pyramidal, ...) has a somehow characteristic average number of in-coming and out-going synaptic connections, i.e. not every type of neuron will have about 10,000 in-coming and 10,000 out-going synaptic connections. I am looking for a thorough **overview of these characteristic numbers by structural type**.
2. I assume that for some functional groups of neurons (see [The human brain in numbers I: neurons](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53587/the-human-brain-in-numbers-i-neurons)) there are characteristic average numbers of in-coming and out-going synaptic connections per neuron. I am looking for a thorough **overview of these characteristic numbers by functional group**.
3. Finally, for some functional groups there are presumably characteristic ratios of inner and outer synaptic connections: "x % of the in-coming synaptic connections of a neuron in group X come from other neurons in this group, the rest comes from the outside. y % of the out-going synaptic connections of a neuron in group X go to other neurons in this group, the rest goes to the outside".  I am looking for a thorough **overview of these characteristic ratios by functional group**.

Comment: Woah, that's just ***too*** broad a question! Divide it into (at least) three questions, lest even a bounty of +500 points is not very likely to get you a complete answer for such a big question...

Comment: Yes, incredibly incredibly too broad. You might look into projects like the Blue Brain Project in Europe and the BRAIN initiative in the US.

Comment: I'd like to, but these are real huge projects with vast web sites. And I am not sure if I would find thorough and concise overviews of the kind I'm looking for. So if anyone knows...

Comment: @hansstricker honestly, if you ain't sure you'd get all that you want even on such vast websites, how do you expect somebody here to pack all of it in a little answer?

Comment: The little answer might be a link that would be hard to find.